# Sending multipart emails with Rails: how to favor the HTML version over the plain text one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, html-email

I setup a standard rails mailer with multipart view following the official guide, like this:

```
mail(to: user.email, subject: "Welcome") do |format|
   format.html { render layout: 'my_layout' }
   format.text
end
```

With the clear and common intent to give priority to the html version of the message, only to find that, as [this article points out](http://www.tui8.com/2012/04/25/how-to-send-multipart-email/), calling `format.html` before the `format.text` makes a lot of mail clients to show only the text version of the message. In my case I verified (and struggled with) that with both Gmail and Mozilla Thunderbird.

Is there a reliable solution to give precedence to the html version?

Comment: i didn't know that there's a precedence when it comes to mailers.  what happens when you remove the block?  we don't pass a block to the mail method if we don't need to pass any specific details. we just provide the html and text templates and they're sent as part of the email.

Comment: Given that I need the block because I need to specify a layout for the html version (I just edited the question to show that), I just made a quick test applying the layout directly to the html message and removing the block: it turns out that without the block it works the right way (precedence to html version).

Comment: The recipient, not the sender, dictates which format they prefer.  If you don't want them to have the option to view text even if that's what they prefer, don't create a text version.

Comment: Check the documentation on configuring the `parts_order` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
Perhaps putting `text/html` before `text/plain` helps

Comment: Seems fixed in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9cf33b55f39779b98604e1652affc2c64873dd9b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is to switch `format.html` with `format.text` so that the text format is called *before* the html one. Which is exactly the *opposite* of what one would expect.

Comment: Placing the `format.text` block first is exactly what one should expect, per MIME RFC 1341. See 7.2.3 on http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

"In general, user agents that compose multipart/alternative entities should place the body parts in increasing order of preference, that is, with the preferred format last."